# Why is the phrase "We assume the reader to have [...]" not ungrammatical

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-usage

In scientific articles I often read the phrase:

> We assume the reader to have [some basic knowledge in] ...

A simple [google search](https://www.google.com/search?ei=6T61XvysGpHjkgXSwIbgCw&q=%22we%20assume%20the%20reader%20to%20have%22%20&oq=%22we%20assume%20the%20reader%20to%20have%22%20&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1CcmwJYnJsCYIGcAmgAcAB4AIABAIgBAJIBAJgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi8xdW5kaTpAhWRsaQKHVKgAbwQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) of it reveals tons of examples. But, strictly, it sound a little bit odd, or ungrammatical? Should it not rather be

> We assume the reader has some basic knowledge

or

> We assume that the reader has some [...]?

Or why is the original form perfectly fine?

Comment: Macmillan includes this usage: **assume** to believe that something is true, even though no one has told you or even though you have no proof... _assume someone/something to be/do[/have/be able to do/ ...] something_: I have always assumed her to be British.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more formal because it's an older grammatical form. It hasn't completely died out yet—rather, it's been relegated to formal usage. But your suggested alternative *we assume the reader has ...* can be used in even the most formal writing today (although I'm not sure this was the case in 1850).

Consider [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suppose+him+to+be%2C+suppose+he+is%2C+suppose+that+he+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuppose%20him%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuppose%20he%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuppose%20that%20he%20is%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csuppose%20him%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuppose%20he%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuppose%20that%20he%20is%3B%2Cc0)

In the first half of the 19th century, the most common expression was *suppose him to be*, but now the most common expression is *suppose he is*. The Ngram for *assume* is similar, but is unfortunately complicated by the fact that the use of *assume* meaning *suppose* was much less common in the 19th century. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=assume+that%2C+suppose+that&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cassume%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuppose%20that%3B%2Cc0). But I assume that the grammar of *assume* and *suppose* behaved similarly.